# Sort list dart with 2 condation for pinned message

Tags: flutter, dart

This code working by sort pinned message and messagePinned bool

```
snapshot.data?.sort((a, b) {
  if(b.c.messagePinned != null) {
    if(b.c.messagePinned!) {
      return 1;
    }
  }
  return -2;
});
```

I want to do it in 2 stages. I want fixed messages at the top and sorted by last message date.
The code below doesn't give what I want

```
snapshot.data?.sort((a, b) {
  if(b.c.messagePinned != null) {
    if(b.c.messagePinned!) {
      return b.c.lastMessageTime.compareTo(
          a.c.lastMessageTime);
      }
   }
   return -2;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that your comparison is backwards for the pinned case.  You want to use `return a.c.lastMessageTime.compareTo(b.c.lastMessageTime);`

Comparing b to a would result in the dates being sorted backwards I think.

As an aside you can also consolidate your if statements.

`if(b.c.messagePinned != null && b.c.messagePinned!) {`

If the first condition is false, the second condition won't be checked.